# How do you create an actual Table of Contents in Filemaker 11

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to create a table of contents in Filemaker based on records sorted by Sub-Summaries.  Is this doable?  Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you want to produce a report with a table of contents?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as long as you have a field 'title' corresponding to the TOC title and another field 'pageNumber' corresponding to a page number.

Create a summary field called 'startPageNumber' equal to the minimum of pageNumber. Now create a sub-summary grouped by 'title' and then sorted by 'startPageNumber' (you'll need to check the box that says 'sort by summary').